# meteor, meteor call method returning nothing?

Tags: meteor

Here is my code in client side

```
var us_exist=Meteor.call('isUserExists',function(e,r){});
console.log(us_exist)// displaying "undefined" in console
if(us_exist==0)
{
    console.log("user not exist")
    Meteor.call('updatePosts',this._id,option_data,function(e,r){});
}
else
{
    console.log("iser exists");
}
```

here is my method in server side

```
isUserExist: function()
{
 var u_exist=Polls_Coll.find({question:this.question}, {option1:{$elemMatch:{ids: u_name}}} );
return u_exist.count()
}
```

It is returning nothing.

**When i run it in my browser console it is working fine and displaying result as 0 or 1.**

Comment: This is a common gotcha, please have a look to this answer of mine : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460123/meteor-methods-returns-undefined/17460481#17460481

Answer (score 0):

The value of the method is not returned from the `call` function, but rather passed as an argument for the callback. So you should put your code inside that empty callback you've got.

```
var self = this;

Meteor.call('isUserExists', function(e, us_exists) {

    console.log(us_exist);
    if(!us_exist) {
      console.log("user not exist")
      Meteor.call('updatePosts', self._id, ...);
    } else {
      console.log("user exists");
    }

});
```

---

By the way, get a habit of not using `==` operator in JavaScript. You'll be much happier without it in the long run.

Comment: What's `u_name` on the server side?